# Is there a trick to cat jumping sideways?

Tags: okami

I'm playing Okami and in "[Inner Yoshpet](http://okami.wikia.com/wiki/Inner_Yoshpet)" there's a pit you have to cross with catprints across the sides.  I don't see a cat statue, and I've managed to stick to the wall sometimes, so I assume that this is an area of permanent catprints that I don't need to brush myself.

But I'm having no luck at all getting across this.  I can make the first landing stick maybe 1/3 of the time, but it looks like you need to land 10 in a row to make it all the way across.

I think I must be missing something here, because it's completely out of proportion with the difficulty of the rest of the game so far.  I've never had *any* puzzle or demon in Okami take more than 3 tries to figure out, and I've never had any trouble at all with sticking to any catprint wall.

Is there a trick to it?  What's the rule about when exactly to hit the button, or which way to aim?  I seem to miss the wall and do a double-jump, even if the camera is tilted so that I'm going 'into' the wall, and then either I can't stick to the wall after a double-jump, or I'm too far away and fall off.  I have noticed that sometimes I'll stick to the wall well below where the catprints are: are they too high, or is the whole wall sticky?  I'm stumped.

UPDATE: I made it past this area, but only after dying many times.  I'm still curious if there's a trick to this, since it seems odd that this one part of a (mandatory) timed race is so much harder than any of the half-dozen-or-so 'bosses' I've faced so far.  Or maybe I'm just really bad at video games.

Comment: I am a little curious which platform you're playing on - I know there were some complaints about unresponsive controls on the Wii version, though I don't know if they ever extended to the wall-climbing mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there's no particular trick to this area beyond timing your jumps correctly.

Here's a [walkthrough video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNatrWcDV8E&t=7m17s) showing someone going through that section - it does look as though the whole wall is a valid surface to stick to.